# wicked_pdf download error in the production server in rails 6 application

Tags: rubygems, production-environment, webpacker, wicked-pdf, ruby-on-rails-6.1

In a Rails 6 application, the wicked_pdf was working fine in the local server. It is downloadable, but in the production server it raised issue. Here is the code

controller.rb

```
def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "Quote Invoice - #{@quote_invoice.id}",
               margin: {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
               template: 'quote_invoices/show.pdf.html.erb',
               formats: [:html],
               layout: "invoice"
      end
      format.html do
        render  template: 'quote_invoices/show', layout: "invoice"
      end
    end
  end
```

in link

```
  <%= link_to eval("client_profile_#{type}_path(client_profile_id: e.client_profile_id, id:  e.id, format: 'pdf' )"), target: "_blank", title: "Download", class: 'btn btn-sm btn-info mb-2' do %>
    <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
  <% end %>
```

initializers/wicked_pdf.rb

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  # Path to the wkhtmltopdf executable: This usually isn't needed if using
  # one of the wkhtmltopdf-binary family of gems.
  # exe_path: '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
  #   or
  # exe_path: Gem.bin_path('wkhtmltopdf-binary', 'wkhtmltopdf')

  # Layout file to be used for all PDFs
  # (but can be overridden in `render :pdf` calls)
  # layout: 'pdf.html',

  # Using wkhtmltopdf without an X server can be achieved by enabling the
  # 'use_xvfb' flag. This will wrap all wkhtmltopdf commands around the
  # 'xvfb-run' command, in order to simulate an X server.
  #
  # use_xvfb: true,
}
```

in gemfile

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

In local server, the pdf download is ok. But in the production server, the following error occurs

> ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat)

in the show action.

How to solve this problem?

I comment out

```
exe_path: '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
```

in the wicked_pdf initializers, but it raised

```
Bad wkhtmltopdf's path: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: Does the actual link generated by your `link_to` end with the `.pdf` extension?

Comment: Yes. <a target="_blank" title="Download" class="btn btn-sm btn-info mb-2" href="/client_profiles/63/general_invoices/34.pdf">
</a>